# chamar método action no controller através de um script da view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma action dentro do meu controller, para fazer download de um arquivo XML, com a seguinte assinatura.
 ***public ActionResult Export(int id){},*** no entendo na minha página tenho um botão que chama um script de download na view, preciso que esse script acione o método de exportar dentro do meu controller passando id como parâmetro. Como faço este acesso?

```
        //Método do controller
    public ActionResult Export(int id)
    {

        var resource = WorkCenterFlow.GetResource(id);
        using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            resource.Export(stream);
            var result = new FileContentResult(stream.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream");
            result.FileDownloadName = string.Format("{0}.bin", (resource.FullName ?? "File").Replace(' ', '_').TrimEnd().TrimStart());
            return result;
        }       
    }
```

Como ficaria o script da view?

```
            downloadParameter: function (e) {
                 ??
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a melhor forma é fazer a chamada via `javascript` mesmo. Algo do tipo

```
$("#btnDownlaod").click(function (e) {
    callPostBack(e, this, @Url.Action("Export", "Nome_Controller", new { id = id_valor }, Request.Url.Scheme), null, SuccessoCallback, ErroCallback);
});

function SuccessoCallback (data) { alert("deu certo"); }

function ErroCallback (MsgErro) { alert("deu errado"); }
```

Comment: Valeu cara, funcionou assim!